# Animating gradients in SVG using JavaScript. Weird behaviour of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am trying to animate a ratings control (star) by updating the gradient coordinates. 
Please find the svg [here](http://codepen.io/agasthyanavaneeth/full/Lbxfr). This is perfectly working in firefox. but in Internet explorer (IE 11), it is not getting rendered. I tried by removing polygons and adding them back. But nothing worked. In chrome, for first second first star is filled, then erased and getting animated! Please look into this.

Thanks in advance :)

**[Update]:**
I am able to produce animation in the control I referred above. check the link. I donot know y, but in IE (ie11) updating a gradient using JavaScript is not updating the polygon using the gradient. In ff & chrome , after updating gradient data we can observe the change in poolygon or some other object using the gradient. So, in IE, rather than updating existing svg oibjects, I started removing object, creating a new object with updated data and added to SVG tree. It started working. But it is an overhead. Anyone can suggest be a better approach! And, initial blink in chrome and IE still exists. As of now, I am hiding the initial blink by using timer function in code after calling *animate()* object. Can anyone help in solving this?

thanks

Comment: That's an incredibly complex script for what you're trying to do.  Are you getting any error messages?  What does your DOM say about the styles?  Why do you have browser-sniffing for MSIE, and what happens when you remove it?

Comment: Yeah. If i add element after some change, it is working fine. Can u suggest me better and elegant approach?